# Generating a random password according to RegEx

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am trying to generate a 6 character password but I want each letter to match correct RegEx.

The RegEx being:

```
[a-z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][!@#$%^&*?+][A-Z]
```

I am currently here:

```
$passwd = @(1..6)
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $passwd.length; $i++){
Get-Random $passwd[$i] 
}
```

But all this is doing is generating 6 random integers.

I want to use the Get-Random cmdlet

Answer (score 1):

It's "generating 6 random integers" because that's exactly what you're telling it to do. `$passwd` is an array of integers 1 through 6, and then you're basically calling `Get-Random` 6 times by looping through that array:

```
Get-Random 1
Get-Random 2
Get-Random 3
Get-Random 4
Get-Random 5
Get-Random 6
```

Instead, you need arrays of each of your allowed/required characters, then select from those, and put them together. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996571/1324345) for a solution to a very similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

```
@(
  [char](97..122 | get-random),
  [char](65..90 | get-random),
  (0..9 | get-random),
  [char](97..122 | get-random),
  ('!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','?',';','+' | get-random),
  [char](65..90 | get-random)
 ) -join ''
```